# Detecting user leaves page with custom popup in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I want to open a popup to warn the user that their data would be lost if they leave the form without submitting it.

I've heard about `Prompt` can do it, but they didn't support I customize the Popup, button, or handling confirmation button or cancel.

is there any way or component that can help me to show the popup prevent the user leaves the form with 2 customize buttons.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use react-confirm-alert

install:

```
npm i react-confirm-alert
```

using:

```
import { confirmAlert } from 'react-confirm-alert';
import 'styles/react-confirm-alert.css';
```

create this customize function

```
const MyCustomConfirm = (content, onAccept, title, acceptTxt, rejectTxt) => {
acceptTxt = acceptTxt || "Yes";
rejectTxt = rejectTxt || "No";
title = title || "Message";
confirmAlert({
    title: title,
    message: <div className="react-confirm-alert-message">{content}</div>,
    buttons: [
        {
            label: acceptTxt,
            className: "btn-secondary", // your own css
            onClick: () => {
                if (onAccept) {
                    onAccept();
                }
            }
        },
        {
            label: rejectTxt,
            className: "btn-secondary", // your own css
            onClick: () => { }
        }
    ]
});
```

}

now you can call it anywhere. example :

```
MyCustomConfirm(' Do you want to clear all ? ', function () {
                    searchInput.val("");
                    $(this).val("");
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my trouble is how to automatic open the popup without firing any event when the user leaves the form, like the way that Prompt is doing. But the Prompt didn't support customize their Popup.

Answer (score 0):

use onBlur event on your parent element of form

```
myFunction = () =>{
     MyCustomConfirm(' Do you want to clear all ? ', function () {
                searchInput.val("");
                $(this).val("");
            });
     return false;
}


render(){
    // your parent element of form
    <form onBlur={this.myFunction()>

    </form>
}
```

or you can call this popup when user try to close your form.
or even the document level you can use this :

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    if (formSubmitting) {
        return undefined;
    }
```